# How to correct video orientation in lua corona?

Tags: lua, orientation, coronasdk, media, landscape

I want to play a video in landscape mode. But Alas! it's being displayed in Potrait mode.

My build.setting file is configured properly. My whole game is in landscape mode but this video orientation thing is disturbing everything.

My code is

```
media.playVideo("media/ending.mp4", false)
```

My build.setting code is

```
settings = {

    android =
    {
        usesPermissions =
        {
            "android.permission.VIBRATE",
        },
    },
    orientation = {
        default = "landscapeRight",
        supported = { "landscapeRight", "landscapeLeft"}
    },

    iphone = {



        plist = {

            UIAppFonts =
            {
                "Literaturnaya Book.ttf"  
            },
            UIStatusBarHidden = false,
            UIPrerenderedIcon = false,
            UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = true,

        },
    },


     androidPermissions =
    {
            "android.permission.INTERNET",
            "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    },
     android =
       {
              usesPermissions =
              {

                 "android.permission.INTERNET",
                  "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE",
                  "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE",
                  "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",

              },
       },

}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you holding the device in Portrait mode?  If yes, try holding it in Landscape and see if it is going to rotate.

Comment: No, I am holding it in Landscape mode. Still facing this problem. Corona SDK sucks.

Comment: Try using native.newVideo() instead

Comment: @rsc I want it for both android and ios devices. And native.newVideo() doesn't work on android.

Believe me corona is the worst sdk. Will be moving to Unity after my game launch.

Comment: Strange, the docs says that native.newVideo work for both Android & iOS....Also the media.playVideo opens the video inside the system media player (like when you are on your phone and opens a video from a site), it is almost as a another app that is handling the video. And as such, it should obey the rotation of the device (not the Corona one). Did you check if your phone is with rotation locked (on the device settings)?

Comment: Just created tested here the media.playVideo on Android device and it is working as said before. It obeys the rotation of the device (it ignores all Corona settings), showing the vide on both Portrait and Landscape.

Comment: @rsc native.newVideo doesn't work on all android devices. As I checked it earlier. And rotation lock was off. Still my video was showing up in portrait mode. Now i converted my video to sprite sheet and implemented it.

Thanks for your time and concern. I am voting up your comment.

Comment: Do u want to send me your video so I can test here? I used a mp4 video and media.playVideo and it was working on both orientations on my Android here...